# Why I can't use pytoch on spyder?

Tags: pytorch

I am using Windows 10 OS, Python Version - 3.8
Installed Method -  `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`

It was successfully installed, when trying to run `torch.cuda.is_available()` throws up an error as -

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'torch' has no attribute 'cuda' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I faced this error other importing such as -torch.nn as nn-
I checked the package list (!pip list ) it is present

Why I can't use pytoch on spyder ? How to tackle this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a file named `torch.py` in your working `directory`
Please rename it to something else